# Should we ask easy questions?

Tags: discussion

We are looking for both new people and new series to be on our site. Is there any merit to the idea of asking easy questions, both to pull in new people who might not want to answer more difficult questions and to start off having questions for series that aren't Naruto, Bleach, Dragonball, or One Piece?

Comment: Related: [Can you ask questions even if the answer is easily found elsewhere?](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/q/112)